# Where i can save the data of user on Frontend with a token jwt system based

Tags: javascript, token, jwt

I need save data of user when user login with token.
How i can save data of user for example her user id , her name , her x data , i think save data in local storage but is it insecure because this data any person can change on the console

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies to store user information but it's storage size is less compared to local storage